# Ошибка при попытке отправить JSON в теле запроса

Tags: java, spring, rest, reactive

Изучаю реактивную джаву.

Суть вопроса: хочу отправить **JSON объект** со следующими данными (`user_id` и `password`) на внешний **API** , для получения токена авторизации.

**Класс JsonEntity:**

```
    public class JsonEntity {
    String user_id;
    String password;

    public JsonEntity() {
        setUser_id("1863");
        setPassword("1830Voldemort");
    }
```

**Контроллер:**

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

@PostMapping("/")
public Mono<JSONObject> getToken(JsonEntity jsonEntity) {
    String url = "https://sandbox.iway.io/transnextgen/v1/auth/login";
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().
            baseUrl(url)
            .build();
    return webClient
            .post()
            .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(Mono.just(jsonEntity), JsonEntity.class)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(JSONObject.class);
}
```

**Стэктрейс:**

```
2021-08-16 14:46:43.356 ERROR 13902 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [5ea48e75-2]  500 Server Error for HTTP POST "/"

org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: failed to resolve 'sandbox.iway.io'; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: failed to resolve 'sandbox.iway.io'
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Request to POST null [DefaultWebClient]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.example.taxitaxidemo.govno.TestController#getToken(JsonEntity) [DispatcherHandler]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.subscribe(MonoErrorSupplied.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4338) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:93) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onError(MonoFlatMapMany.java:204) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.whenError(FluxRetryWhen.java:225) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenOtherSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:274) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:414) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:251) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.drain(EmitterProcessor.java:491) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.tryEmitNext(EmitterProcessor.java:299) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManySerialized.tryEmitNext(SinkManySerialized.java:100) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalManySink.emitNext(InternalManySink.java:27) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:190) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:189) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect$ClientTransportSubscriber.onError(HttpClientConnect.java:304) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.9.jar:1.0.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:189) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onError(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:172) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.9.jar:1.0.9]
        at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.AbstractPool$Borrower.fail(AbstractPool.java:444) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.9.jar:1.0.9]
        at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.lambda$drainLoop$9(SimpleDequePool.java:399) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.9.jar:1.0.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(FluxDoOnEach.java:186) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:189) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnectionAllocator$PooledConnectionInitializer.onError(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:554) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.9.jar:1.0.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:192) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:259) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:106) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4338) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar:3.4.8]
        at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector$MonoChannelPromise.tryFailure(TransportConnector.java:517) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.9.jar:1.0.9]
        at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector.lambda$doResolveAndConnect$11(TransportConnector.java:324) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.9.jar:1.0.9]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:552) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:609) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure(DefaultPromise.java:109) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver$2.operationComplete(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:86) ~[netty-resolver-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:571) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:550) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:609) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.finishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1054) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:999) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:417) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.access$600(DnsResolveContext.java:65) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext$2.operationComplete(DnsResolveContext.java:466) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:571) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:550) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:609) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext.tryFailure(DnsQueryContext.java:225) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext$4.run(DnsQueryContext.java:177) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:170) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:469) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: failed to resolve 'sandbox.iway.io'
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.finishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1046) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:999) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:417) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.access$600(DnsResolveContext.java:65) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext$2.operationComplete(DnsResolveContext.java:466) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:571) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:550) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:609) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext.tryFailure(DnsQueryContext.java:225) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext$4.run(DnsQueryContext.java:177) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:170) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:469) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolverTimeoutException: [/192.168.43.1:53] query via UDP timed out after 5000 milliseconds (no stack trace available)
```

Comment: @karashal, спасибо за поправки)

Answer (score -2):

`DnsNameResolverTimeoutException` случается, если не получен ответ от dns в заданное время (5 секунд).

Попробуйте еще раз или используйте другой dns сервер.

Comment: физический доступ к серверу имеется, через постман запросы идут нормально

Comment: К какому серверу имеется физический доступ? Ваша програма с TestController  запускается на каком компьютере, когда возникает проблема? На локальном?

Comment: https://sandbox.iway.io/transnextgen/v1/auth/login к этому серверу, тестил через постман. Моя программа запускается на локальной машине, проблема возникает когда я пытаюсь отправить json из контроллера